# How to remove specific duplicate line in Notepad++

Tags: ip, notepad++, regex

Hello i have tried to remove duplicates in a text file using TextFX plugin in notepad++ but it's didn't works for this type of text

```
209.116.247.120|admin|default|Taiwan (TW)|Tai-pei|Taipei|Unknown
209.116.247.120|admin|default|
209.116.49.130|admin|admin
209.116.49.130|admin|admin|China (CN)|Henan|Zhengzhou|Unknown
209.116.55.142|admin|admin
209.116.55.142|admin|admin|Korea, Republic of (KR)|Seoul-t'ukpyolsi|Seoul|Unknown
209.116.65.26|admin|admin
209.116.65.26|admin|admin|New Zealand (NZ)|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown
```

As you can see there's duplicates with added countries so i would like to remove these duplicates

```
209.116.247.120|admin|default|
209.116.49.130|admin|admin
209.116.55.142|admin|admin
209.116.65.26|admin|admin
```

or whether these duplicates

```
209.116.247.120|admin|default|Taiwan (TW)|Tai-pei|Taipei|Unknown
209.116.49.130|admin|admin|China (CN)|Henan|Zhengzhou|Unknown
209.116.55.142|admin|admin|Korea, Republic of (KR)|Seoul-t'ukpyolsi|Seoul|Unknown
209.116.65.26|admin|admin|New Zealand (NZ)|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown
```

If someone have any idea or regex command to fix this, I would appreciate it please And give commands for both thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Only if duplicates are consecutive:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(([^|]+[|][^|]+[|][^|]+)[|]?.*)\R\2`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
(           : start group 1
  (         : start group 2
    [^|]+   : 1 or more NON pipe character |
    [|]     : a pipe
    [^|]+   : 1 or more NON pipe character |
    [|]     : a pipe
    [^|]+   : 1 or more NON pipe character |
  )         : end group 2
  [|]?      : a pipe, optional
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
)           : end group 1
\R          : any kind of line break
\2          : backreference to group 2
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group, the first dupplicate line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
209.116.247.120|admin|default|Taiwan (TW)|Tai-pei|Taipei|Unknown|
209.116.49.130|admin|admin|China (CN)|Henan|Zhengzhou|Unknown
209.116.55.142|admin|admin|Korea, Republic of (KR)|Seoul-t'ukpyolsi|Seoul|Unknown
209.116.65.26|admin|admin|New Zealand (NZ)|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day :) is there any chat box in stack where i can chat with you if i get any problem?

Comment: @VickyMalhotra: Your welcome, glad it helps. I don't know if there is a chat here.

Comment: @VickyMalhotra: Sorry but I prefer to exchange on this site.

Comment: ok no problem man :) i hope there's an option of chatting or instead i will mention you in comments because i get many type of Notepad++ errors and i need help for that :( and you seems you have good knowledge of regex command in notepad++!